# Flash in Magento CMS

Tags: flash, magento, content-management-system

i want to add flash banner on magento home page using xml or cms could any one help me please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension might help you
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/FME+Extensions/extension/3382/banners